# Laravel validación de multiples arrays

Tags: laravel

Tengo un servicio que recibe varios arrays `[ [], [], [], ]`, la validación la hago con un FormRequest, no todos los arrays tienen la misma estructura que es donde tengo el problema porque dependiendo del valor de un campo otros pueden estar o no.

Asi es como tengo mis reglas de validación:

```php
return [
    '*.amount' => [ 'required', 'min:3', 'max:10', ],
    '*.description' => [ 'nullable', 'max:250', ],
    '*.method' => [ 'required', Rule::in([ 'spei', 'services', 'atm', ]), ],

    '*.customer.firstname' => [ 'required', 'min:3', 'max:50', ],
    '*.customer.lastname' => [ 'required', 'min:3', 'max:50', ],
    '*.customer.email' => [ 'required', 'email', ],
    '*.customer.phone' => [
        Rule::requiredIf(function () {
            return 'atm' == request()->input('method');
        }),
        'max:10',
    ],
];
```

El problema es que el campo `*.customer.phone` solo se valida si `*.method` es atm, pero dentro de la validación `requiredIf` no estoy obteniendo el array que se esta validando `request()->input('method')`

Hay alguna manera de obtener el array que se esta validando?

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno creo que me hizo bien redactar la pregunta, hice un cambio y ya me funciona.

```php
...
'*.customer.phone' => [
    'required_if:*.method,atm',
    'digits:10',
],
...
```

Saludos.